CSS how to target the caption of one individual image?
I can use .wp-element-caption to change all site captions at once, but I want to target one specific caption at a time. Because I'm adding additional CSS to a premade WP theme, I can't find a way to assign additional CSS classes to captions, only to the images they're attached to.
The image whose caption I'm trying to target is called ginkgo-1. I've tried .ginkgo-1#wp-element-caption and similar variations with no luck. What would the correct syntax be to target that caption?

You can do the inspect element in the chrome and see if there is any unique class added for that image something like image-123, if yes you can use that.
If you can provide me the link to the page were image is used and image, I can provide you what exact css class you can use.

Thanks! It's on https://thymeandspacedesign.com/commissions/ and the issue is that every caption on the site has the class 'wp-element-caption' with no way to assign unique classes using WP.

You can use the Parent class of the caption which is added for each image and they are different for e.g. the below code will add the css to the caption of the second image in past commision section
#ginkgo-2 .wp-element-caption{
background:#000000 !important;
color:#ffffff !important;

